# docker data volume vs kubernetes persistent storage

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

docker engine supports [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#remove-volumes)

> A Docker data volume persists after a container is deleted

[`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) and [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) both support it:

1. `docker run --volume data_vol:/mount/point`
2. docker-compose with named volumes using top-level `volumes` key

kubernetes also supports [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), but **does it support the same concept of having a data volume - that is, a volume which resides within a container?**

if kubernetes supports a data volume (within a container):

1. would appreciate any reference to the documentation (or an example)
2. does it also support the migration of the data volume in the same manner it supports the migration of regular containers?

i found some [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062547/docker-volume-vs-kubernetes-persistent-volume), but couldn't get the answer i am looking for.

Comment: Persistent local storage/volumes is the closest in kubernetes to what you ask: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/ 2) no, it won't be migrated: you allocate it explicitly manually on a particular node.

Comment: "a volume which resides within a container" --- it does not reside within a container in docker case as well: it's created externally and then mounted inside container on start.

Comment: @zerkms: it created a mount point from the host (worker) node to the container, whereas i am interested in a data container. so the link doesn't cover my user case and not answering my question. if you think i missed anything in the link, please clarify.

Comment: @zerkms: "it does not reside within a container in docker case as well" meaning, it is managed by the docker engine (of course it resides on the disk somewhere); as you can see in my post, when using `docker run` the argument for `--volume` is not an absolute path

Comment: "so the link doesn't cover my user case" --- you did not reveal your use case, it's hard to guess.

Comment: @zerkms: updated my post and marked in bold my question. and thank you for the quick replies - much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222143/discussion-between-mr-and-zerkms).

Comment: Just changing it from regular font to bold does not make it more clear: "a volume which resides within a container" --- there is no such thing in docker, in docker a volume created externally and then mounted inside. Every volume type in kubernetes does the same.

Comment: You might find answer in [kuberenetes volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) docs

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to say is:

If you do not specify a host path for a docker volume mount, docker dynamically provisions a path and persist it between restarts.

**"that is, a volume which resides within a container"**
Volume is generated outside of container and mounted later.

For example:

```sh
# data_vol location is decided by docker installation
docker run --volume data_vol:/mount/point

# host path is explicitly given
docker run --volume /my/host/path:/mount/point
```

In kubernetes terms, this is similar to dynamic provisioning. If you want dynamic provisioning, you need to have Storage classes depending on your storage backend.

Please read https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/ .

If you want to specify a host path, following is an example. You can also achieve similar results by using NFS, block storage etc.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /home/user/my-vol
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-ss
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-ss
  serviceName: my-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-ss
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ubuntu
          name: my-container
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /my-vol
              name: my-vol
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: my-vol
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            app: my-ss
```