# To verify my understanding is correct about "volume" defined in Dockerfile & specified in StatefulSet manifest of k8s

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am using kubernetes to deploy a postgresql pod.

My k8s manifest for that works nicely. I only paste the relevant code below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgresql
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgresql
        image: postgres:14
      ...
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-postgres
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
        ...

  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: my-postgres
    spec:
```

As you can see above, under container spec, I declared the `volumeMounts` with a mount path. And a `volumeClaimTemplates` to provision the persistent in cloud.

Like said, it works fine.

when I open the Dockerfile of [official postgresql here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4e56664f1797ba4cc0f5917b6d794792a5571b45/14/bullseye/Dockerfile). On line 186, there is `VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data`.

I would like to verify if I understand the whole thing correctly:

1. Is it so that the line 186 `VOLUME ...` in postgres Dockerfile is only meant to tell its official mount point? I mean if I use the Dockerfile to run a container, it DOESN'T create a volume but I need to specific a volume & mount to that mount point. Am I right here?
2. In my k8s manifest above, under `volumeMounts:` the `mountPath:` value has to be exactly the same as the line 186 `VOLUME ...` in postgres Dockerfile, because that is the mount point they told. Am I right here?

Comment: I wanted to answer, however I realized I'm not sure about all the details to give you a proper answer. But just a few notes. the `VOLUME` part in a `Dockerfile` just means that whenever you run this image, it will automatically mount the path specified to something like `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. You can override the mount path by providing `-v` option when running `docker run`. In kubernetes, the default volume is not enough to actually persist data, because this directory is gonna be either deleted or simply not accessible when you restart your pod.

Comment: Regarding `mountPath`, you can mount any directory on the container, it would work even if this docker image didn't have the `VOLUME` specified in its `Dockerfile`. For your setup, this is indeed the correct path to where postgres stores its data, but it's not because they have specified `VOLUME`, it's simply because this is where `postgres` stores the data.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53068092/10020419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I created simple Dockerfile to examine "VOLUME" instruction in Dockerfile as below :

```
[root@machine stack]# cat Dockerfile
FROM busybox
VOLUME /insidecontiner
RUN echo "writing From Container" >> /insidecontiner/file
CMD sleep 1000

[root@machine stack]# docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   7.68kB
Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
 ---> 69593048aa3a
Step 2/4 : VOLUME /insidecontiner
 ---> Running in 71188c3529d8
Removing intermediate container 71188c3529d8
 ---> 6a83730242a2
Step 3/4 : RUN echo "writing From Container" >> /insidecontiner/file
 ---> Running in d73b82b60333
Removing intermediate container d73b82b60333
 ---> c2cfb57a967d
Step 4/4 : CMD sleep 1000
 ---> Running in aff9f1d4a0b3
Removing intermediate container aff9f1d4a0b3
 ---> 834cc7a98e91
Successfully built 834cc7a98e91
```

- There were no docker volumes in the system before running this contaainer

```
[root@machine stack]# docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
```

- Once i created a container using this image , It automatically created a docker volume

```
[root@machine ~]# docker run -d --name boo test
e5994bb0975635354f60a238c19db472700949946c15b6a916e0c2e4ffed33e3

[root@machine ~]# docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               2d7ec8ea6f61cd4c8758d2da666b11b28970b9ff630053bd4109a13f4516c504

[root@machine ~]# docker volume inspect 2d7ec8ea6f61cd4c8758d2da666b11b28970b9ff630053bd4109a13f4516c504
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-06-11T13:03:05-04:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/2d7ec8ea6f61cd4c8758d2da666b11b28970b9ff630053bd4109a13f4516c504/_data",
        "Name": "2d7ec8ea6f61cd4c8758d2da666b11b28970b9ff630053bd4109a13f4516c504",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

- That volume is mounted inside the container at `/insidecontiner`  :

```
[root@machine ~]# docker exec -it boo /bin/sh
/ # df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  50.0G     18.7G     31.3G  37% /
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    62.8G         0     62.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/rhel-root

                         50.0G     18.7G     31.3G  37% /insidecontiner
```

> > > Coming to your question "Is it so that the line 186 VOLUME ... in postgres Dockerfile is only meant to tell its official mount point? I mean if I use the Dockerfile to run a container, it DOESN'T create a volume but I need to specific a volume & mount to that mount point. Am I right here?"

---

- `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is the place where postgres keeps in datbases
- It does create a volume automatically
- It mounts inside the container to the location mention in the Dockerfile

---

**Now to Kubernetes behavior**

- Creating a pod without mentioning any volumes in pod yaml run the pod successfully.ContainerRuntime on the worker node(docker in this example) will a local docker volume for that container inside the pod

```
[root@machine stack]# kubectl run boo --image prasasai/test
pod/boo created

[root@machine stack]# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE                                     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
boo    1/1     Running   0          3m51s   192.168.187.80   machine1  <none>           <none>

[root@machine1 ~]# docker volume inspect 4dbf6bc943a55c89a45d01c4aa3e860141bb7efe01ce046959c5a208dfab7e3e
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-06-11T17:26:11-04:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4dbf6bc943a55c89a45d01c4aa3e860141bb7efe01ce046959c5a208dfab7e3e/_data",
        "Name": "4dbf6bc943a55c89a45d01c4aa3e860141bb7efe01ce046959c5a208dfab7e3e",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

- If i mention `volumeMounts` section matching the `VOLUME` in Dockerfile then kubernetes is taking care of the volume mapping and ContainerRuntime is not creating the volume :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: boo
  name: boo
spec:
  containers:
  - image: prasasai/test
    name: boo
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mount1
      mountPath: /insidecontiner
  volumes: 
  - name: mount1 
    hostPath:
      path: /here
```

```
[root@machine stack]# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE                                     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
boo    1/1     Running   0          13s   192.168.187.85   machine1   <none>           <none>

[root@machine1 ~]# docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
```

> > > " In my k8s manifest above, under volumeMounts: the mountPath: value has to be exactly the same as the line 186 VOLUME ... in postgres Dockerfile, because that is the mount point they told. Am I right here?"

---

- Yes , Thats absolutely correct.

---

Answer (score 0):

In simple way,

`VOLUME` in Dockerfile creates and `random unnamed` volumes when you run it without mounting it to any point by default.

**NO** it is not equalent to the one you have in k8s manifest.
**Volume** in Dockerfile is more of a metadata to the image and the manifest k8 file is definition of what pod needs to mount with.

**You don't have to copy mountpath in dockerfile**. Just mention it when you are deploying it.

- Example:

`docker run -v myvolume:/my/mountpath myimage`

Answer (score -1):

if I understood you correctly, your question is "*why is a volume specified in the dockerfile, if there is no volume created during the deployment of the container?*"

postgresql needs a directory to write its data to. if the default configuration for postgresql is set to /var/lib/postgresql/data, the application expects that it can write its data into that directory.

when deploying postgresql in a classic, non containerized manner, it would start to write the data into this directory path which would be available on the operating system of the host it was installed on.

when deploying postgresql as a container, the operating system is virtualized by your container engine and therefore the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" is the directory *inside* of the container. that means if you restart it, all data would be lost, because it is not persisted on the host it was deployed to.

if you want to keep your data, even if the container restarts, you have to mount a volume inside the container during runtime which keeps on living after the container is stopped.

**TL;DR:**

1. yes, you are correct. a volume to persist the data has to be created outside of the container and has to be mounted during the deployment onto "/var/lib/postgresql/data" if you don't alter the default configuration.
2. yes, you are correct here as well, because it is basically the same mechanism. for the container, it doesn't matter how you provide the volume and the mechanism differ in kubernetes, docker and the other container engines. when deploying on kubernetes, volumes and volumeMounts are the correct way of configuring this behaviour.

Comment: I beg to differ, and strongly so. To quote from the docs: "The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with the specified name and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or other containers." Note that we are talking of a mount point, not a volume. OP could well mount a volume to `/var/lib`, in which the VOLUME directive will be ignored by the runtime altogether.

Comment: OP actually would like to verify line 186 `VOLUME` of postgres Dockerfile is meant as a mount point. @MarkusWMahlberg your answer says no but your comment here seems is saying yes, I get confused. Am I right in my 1st statement or not in my OP?  Thanks for pointing out I could mount volume to a different path & that would ignore that `VOLUME` instruction in postgres Dockerfile.

Comment: @user842225 Actually both say no, as a volume and a mount point are two different concepts.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg hows your answer different from what I stated? you point out that we are talking about a mount point and not a volume, and this is exactly what my answer says: "a volume has to be created outside of the container and has to be mounted during the deployment"

even this part in your answer "What you do NOT need to do is to mount it to that specific directory" is already included in mine: "has to be mounted during the deployment onto "/var/lib/postgresql/data" if you don't alter the default configuration."

Comment: There is a difference between a mount point, a volume that is mounted to it and whether this is done by the runtime and/or the provisioning. Also, "if you do not alter the default configuration" is both a bit imprecise (which configuration), if not outright incorrect (you can mount a volume to `/var`, and the container will run happily without the configuration of postresql being touched in any way, shape or form).

Answer (score -1):

> Is it so that the line 186 VOLUME ... in postgres Dockerfile is only meant to tell its official mount point? I mean if I use the Dockerfile to run a container, it DOESN'T create a volume but I need to specific a volume & mount to that mount point. Am I right here?

Yes and no. You need to specify a volume and mount it to achieve persistence, that much is correct. What you do NOT need to do is to mount it to that specific directory (though I would advice to do so).

> In my k8s manifest above, under volumeMounts: the mountPath: value has to be exactly the same as the line 186 VOLUME ... in postgres Dockerfile, because that is the mount point they told. Am I right here?

No. You could well mount your volume anywhere into the path of `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, say `/var/lib/postgresql/`. Technically. However, that comes with its own caveats.

However, all in all, you are really reinventing the wheel. You might want to look into [helm charts](https://helm.sh), specifically [bitnami's PostgreSQL helm chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/postgresql/helm).

Comment: Thanks, you kinda answered my question but also a "no" feeling in a sense. So I got your answers but for question 1, what is the purpose of that line 186 VOLUME in postgres Dockerfile if that is not meant as a mount point?  That also affect my understanding for your 2nd answer, I believe you are right & I could mount volume anywhere but again what is the purpose of that VOLUME if it is not a default mount point? Or is it? if it is a mount point (default one) then my 2nd statement should be correct I feel, even though you are also right.

Comment: Its meant as a "failsafe", if you wish. The author of the docker file provides instructions to create a mount point there and (depending on the runtime and orchestration you are using) a volume to be mounted there. However, k8s for example does not honor that. So, for running in standalone docker, a volume would be created at the mount point denoted in the VOLUME instruction, but in k8s, that is not the case.

Comment: "but in k8s, that is not the case", could you please elaborate more there, I fully understand the difference between mount point and volume, my confusion here is that if the Postgres Dockerfile has VOLUME instruction telling where Postgres is writing its data to, that's `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, how does k8s change the path inside the container to write its data to different path in the container?  Yes, I know I can specify a volumen with whatever path because outside the container, but you are saying k8s can alter the data writing path, I would like to know more to understand clearly.

Comment: Put simply: In k8s, `VOLUME`directives are simply not obeyed. k8s cannot change the PostgreSQL config, but you can mount your volume at any point in the path of `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, if you choose to do so, and still have persistence: `/var/`, `/var/lib`, etc...